# Compare DateTime and Interval in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have this class:

```
class Monitor(db.Model):
    '''
    Base Monitor class.
    '''
    __tablename__ = 'monitor'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    last_checked = db.Column(db.DateTime(timezone=False))
    poll_interval = db.Column(db.Interval(),
                              default=datetime.timedelta(seconds=300))
```

And I have this query where I attempt to return only objects that haven't been checked since (now - interval):

```
monitors = db.session.query(Monitor).\
           filter(or_(Monitor.last_checked < (datetime.utcnow() - Monitor.poll_interval)),
                      Monitor.last_checked == None).\
           all()
```

But the query returns nothing. I'm having a hard time figuring out the proper way to do this. Am I on the right track or am I missing something? I'm using MySQL as the database.

Comment: you can print out a Query object (i.e., what you have before you call `.all()`) to get the actual SQL that will be run.  the only guess i have is that SQLA doesn't know to use the wacky `date - INTERVAL 3 DAYS` syntax

Comment: Here's what it gives me.

    `SELECT monitor.id AS monitor_id, monitor.last_checked AS monitor_last_checked, monitor.poll_interval AS monitor_poll_interval
    FROM monitor
    WHERE monitor.last_checked < :poll_interval_1 - monitor.poll_interval`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your parenthesis are wrong. I believe what you want is:

```
monitors = db.session.query(Monitor).\
       filter(or_(Monitor.last_checked < (datetime.utcnow() - Monitor.poll_interval),
                  Monitor.last_checked == None)).\
       all()
```